# What is better: Select vs Threads?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, algorithm, select

In linux.

I want to build an autoclicker that will have an enable/disable function when a key is pressed. Obviously there should be 2 things running in parallel (the clicker itself, and the enable/disable function)

What are the cons and pros of each implementation:
Using a thread which will handle the autoclicking function and another main thread (for the enable/disable etc...)
Or using the syscall select and wait for input/keyboard?

Comment: You _can_ do it either way. What measurements define "better" here?

Comment: I just want to know what are the advantages of each option

Comment: @Jah: Then you should have asked that, instead of asking which was "better".

Comment: "which is better" questions are *usually* not good for SO, since they are likely to be subjective and argumentive. First, try to rephrase the question as "what are the pros and cons of each", second - it also might be a bit subjective sometimes, if you can focus your scope to something more specific - it will probably be even better.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `select` is better for performance, especially when you could have potentially hundreds of simultaneous operations. However it can be difficult to write the code correctly and the style of coding is very different from traditional single threaded programming. For example, you need to avoid calling any blocking methods as it could block your entire application.

Most people find using threads simpler because the majority of the code resembles ordinary single threaded code. The only difficult part is in the few places where you need interthread communication, via mutexes or other synchronization mechanisms.

In your specific case it seems that you will only need a small number of threads,  so I'd go for the simpler programming model using threads.

Comment: Citation needed for first sentence. I suspect on modern systems it's a lot more complicated than that. Certainly with *many* file descriptors in action, threads allow the kernel to simply wake up the thread which is blocked rather than `select` having to repeatedly scan `N` bits in an array and add/remove itself from a wait queue for each. Threads also seem to be able to optimize for the fewest user-kernel transitions. There may be other orthogonal reasons threads are slower, but I don't think it's such a simple clear-cut matter.

Answer (score 2):

Given the amount of work you're doing, it probably doesn't matter.

For high performance applications, there is a difference. In these cases, you need to be handling several thousand connections simultaneously; in such cases, you hand off new connections to new threads.

Creating several thousand threads is expensive, so selecting is used for efficiency. Actually different techniques such as `kqueue` or `epoll` are used for optimal switching.

I say it doesn't matter, because you're likely only going to create the thread once and have exactly two threads running for the lifetime of the application.